# Имеются ли условные операторы IF NOT EXIST для CREATE TABLE?

Tags: php, firebird

Если нет возможности в `FireBird 2.5` добавить констуркцию подобно `MySQL` то как правильнее проверять наличие создаваемой таблицы.

Вопрос касается динамического создания таблиц скриптом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имеются. Нужно проверять наличие записи в системной таблице RDB$RELATIONS. Но есть нюанс! IF работает только в PSQL, но в нем нельзя делать CREATE.
Поэтому приходится дважды оборачивать. IF в EXECUTE BLOCK, а CREATE в EXECUTE STATEMENT. Вот пример:

```
EXECUTE BLOCK
AS
BEGIN
  IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM RDB$RELATIONS WHERE RDB$RELATION_NAME = 'MY_TABLE')) THEN
    EXECUTE STATEMENT '
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)';
END
```

Comment: Если дело происходит внутри процедуры, то EXECUTE BLOCK не нужен, т.к. вы уже пишете процедуру на PSQL